# DCOM in .net (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, dcom

i have an old delphi code with TDCOMConnection component (ComputerName and ServerGUID properties are defined). Now I need to write same application on C#. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: This seems to be a DataSnap (aka MIDAS) client application - see http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/de/MConnect.TDCOMConnection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you have a look at WCF (Windows Communication Foundation).  Google it, there are lots of articles and questions about it, for example:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/773240ad-28ca-4af8-a563-abdd91e70de5.  It gives you lots of flexibility about how your components communicate with each other.

Comment: your should post the final link - What Is Windows Communication Foundation - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx